# How to call a method implemented by user from a different class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I supply my object a path to where sits 'file.py' and I need to call a method from it called 'compress'

**file.py**

```
def compress(arg):
    return arg-5
```

**other.py**

```
class Algorithm:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path #/PATH/TO/file.py

    def func(self, arg1):
        return self.path.compress(arg1)
```

Of course this is a dummy example, but how do I implement func in the right way ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the importlib module you could dynamically load the appropriate path and then call the appropriate function from this module! A simple example using `os.path`:

```
import importlib
my_module = importlib.import_module('os.path')
my_module.exists("/non_existing_path")
```

In this case, you might want to do some additional checks such as file existence and function existence.